# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I met a awkward problem.

```
TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

my code:

```
    for c in input_s:
        if ord('a') <= ord(c.lower()) <= ord('z'):
            e_count += 1
```

I expected that `for c in input_s` which is `string` and the `c` always character is assinged. This happens very rarely, so very hard to regenerate the problem. Is there any case the `c` variable has length2 string?

Comment: Please show us the `input_s` list...

Comment: `e_count  = sum(ord('a') <= ord(c.lower()) <= ord('z') for c in input_s)`

Comment: @StephenRauch `e_count = sum('a' <= c.lower() <= 'z' for c in input_s)` (But still does not answer the question.)

Comment: Consider adding `if len(c)!=1: print(c)` to the loop before the comparison. This may help you find the offending string. Also, make sure you do not have any other `ord`s in your code.

Comment: @DYZ, Actually yours likely would answer the question because it would remove the str len 2 error.

Comment: @StephenRauch It may hide the problem but not solve it. Why would an element of a string be a string with more than one character?

Comment: @DYZ, agree absolutely, but...

Comment: First, tell us what string you typed for the value of `input_s`? It happens when you type some characters not accepted by `ord()` like `ç`.

Comment: @hygull in python3 there is no problem like this and Keanu can you share us how you create `input_s`, and problem is not relevant whit it. It's a type mismatching problem

Comment: Yeah, that is right. @Keanu has mentioned both `python` & `python3` as tags. Not sure which version Python he's using.

Comment: input_s is huge and very diverse so that I can not give you one or two sentence example. But it is literal from multilingual sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if `c` is one code point, `c.lower()` may be multiple. For example, with U+0130 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE, which lowercases to a regular `i` followed by a U+0307 COMBINING DOT ABOVE:

```
>>> x = '\u0130'
>>> len(x)
1
>>> len(x.lower())
2
```

The same can happen with `c.upper()`. One particularly famous case is the [eszett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F):

```
>>> x = 'ß'
>>> x.upper()
'SS'
>>> len(x)
1
>>> len(x.upper())
2
```

Your `ord(c.lower())` call is fundamentally incorrect. If you want to test whether a character is an uppercase or lowercase ASCII letter, you can use [`isascii`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isascii) to test whether a character lies in the 0-127 ASCII range and [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to test whether it's an alphabetical character. You can also use these methods to test whole strings at once. For example,

```
if input_s.isascii() and input_s.isalpha():
    ...
```

would test whether `input_s` is a nonempty string containing only ASCII alphabetical characters. (The "nonempty" part is because `isalpha` returns False for empty strings.)

`isascii` is very new, introduced in Python 3.7. If you have to support older Python versions, you can test individual characters for ASCII-ness with `'\x00' <= c <= '\x7f'` or `0 <= ord(c) <= 127`, or you can hardcode which ranges are ASCII letters and test characters for ASCII-letter-ness with `'A' <= c <= 'Z' or 'a' <= c <= 'z'`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using tuple(or any sequence) for input_s.
If the  first element in your sequence is a string of length 2, you would get the same error.
If its the case, you use a string(or split the sequence), the code should work fine.

Comment: How can you be so sure? If the OP used a tuple, the code would never work. The OP claims that the error is very rare.

Comment: It would be a sequence(list, tuple or set) if not tuple, otherwise the error would not make sense

Comment: Nope you can say the comming data is not a char, but you can't say what it is

Comment: Changing my initial answer to "maybe"
Being it a sequence is a probability. If the input is a sequence and the first item is a string of length 2, the code would give the same error. It all depends on what the input_s. 
There might a lot other reasons.